# Is Western Digital external HDD encryption still flawed?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

There were research and reports in 2015 explaining major flaws in Western Digital external HDD encryption. WD acknowledged those flaws. I have searched for more recent info about whether these flaws still exist, if there are firmware updates, etc. but haven't found much. My current WD Security application is dated 2015 so I'm concerned. Does anyone have any updates on this?

Should I even bother with that and simply use Veracrypt partitions on my drives?

Comment: If your drive is not patched, then by definition, it is not fixed. If your question is about the available firmware updates, that's really a question for WD support.

Comment: See https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=13213

Answer (score 2):

To answer to your last question: definitely.

I would never put trust in a piece of crypto software of which you cannot determine how it works, as is the case with most of these closed firmware security functions within hard drives, or shipped utilities. Please research the [Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) why this is so important.

Open sourced cryptography software is not an absolute guarantee of a proper cryptography implementation, however it makes it more easy to spot issues, and even more important, to correct them. Veracrypt (and its precursor Truecrypt) are well tested and [audited](http://istruecryptauditedyet.com/), so can be trusted with your secrets.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. Some 2015 articles called Western Digital My Passport drives "useless" due to a 32-bit function that comes before the 256-bit encryption and makes it easy to hack for semi-sophisticated users. In other words, they'd choose the weakest link in the system.

I called WD tech support and someone with only vague knowledge kept emphasizing "256-bit" and didn't want to go deeper.

According to [another article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1002.pdf) (where the author added critical context), this problem only affected drives made from 2007-2013, so presumably, the weakness was fixed, but details would be useful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Could you please add links to the articles you are referencing?

Comment: https://www.theregister.com/2015/10/20/western_digital_bad_hard_drive_encryption/  https://www.vice.com/en/article/mgbmma/some-popular-self-encrypting-hard-drives-have-really-bad-encryption

Comment: Somehow my "Update" addition to my first post got deleted - by moderator? I learned that this issue probably only applies to WD hard drives made between 2007 and 2013. See original paper that described the problem: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1002.pdf